# How can I modify the soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to modify my virtual keyboard for a particular `EditText`. And that modification is I want to hide the "comma" character from the virtual keyboard.

I would also like to replace the enter button with done and cancel buttons.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a keyboard on your own.

Here's a How To: to replace your keyboard: http://www.simplemobilereview.com/change-your-android-soft-keyboard-system/

Here you see how you can customize the keyboard: http://www.droid-life.com/2010/04/22/create-your-own-custom-htc_ime-keyboard/

good luck!